# Multiple functions on one event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

So the logic behind my question:

I have a list like this:

```
    <ul>
      <li>
       <a href="#edit" data-transition="fade" class="editLink" data-kms="1" data-date="2015-06-02">Edit</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#edit" data-transition="fade" class="editLink" data-kms="2" data-date="2015-06-02">Edit</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#edit" data-transition="fade" class="editLink" data-kms="3" data-date="2015-06-02">Edit</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

So when I press Edit link, I must collect  `data-kms` and `data-date` by using this function, and put them into `localStorage`:

```
function setCurrent() {
        //Set localStorage items for clicked element
        localStorage.setItem('currentKms', $(this).data('kms'));
        localStorage.setItem('currentDate', $(this).data('date'));

        //Get data
        var kms = localStorage.getItem('currentKms');
        var date = localStorage.getItem('currentDate');

        //Insert data into edit form
        $('#editKms').val(kms);
        $('#editDate').val(date);
    }
```

And then I want to delete that entry from local storage using this function:

```
function deleteRun() {
        //Get Current Data
        var currentKms = localStorage.getItem('currentKms');
        var currentDate = localStorage.getItem('currentDate');

        var runs = getRunsObject();
        var i = 0;

        //Loop throuh runs and remove current run from 'runs' object
        while (i < runs.length) {
            //Remove Current Run
            if (runs[i].kms == currentKms && runs[i].date == currentDate) {
                runs.splice(i, 1);
                alert('Run Deleted');
            } else {
                alert('Run cant be deleted!');
            }
            //Save array without current run
            localStorage.setItem('runs', JSON.stringify(runs));
            i++;
        }

        //Show Runs Again
        $('.original').hide();
        showRuns();
        //Preventing form from submiting
        return false;

    }
```

So basically I have to run 2 functions on 1 event at the same time.
And I'm trying to do it like this:

```
$('.deleteLink').on('tap', function(){
    setCurrent();
    deleteRun();
});
```

But for some reason `setCurrent` doesn't save the data as it supposed to, it sets values to `undefined` instead.

But if I run it like this:

```
  $('.deleteLink').on('tap', setCurrent);
```

It works fine, and it's actually setting correct values to currentKms & currentDate.

So how do I correctly run both of this functions on same event? Because

```
 function(){
    setCurrent();
    deleteRun();
 });
```

isn't working in my case for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

As per your approach `this` in the function `setCurrent` doesn't refers to the element which invoked the event.

You can use [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

> The `call()` method calls a function with a given `this` value and arguments provided individually.

```
$('.deleteLink').on('tap', function(){
    setCurrent.call(this);
    deleteRun();
});
```

---

You can use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

*Code*

```
$('.deleteLink').on('tap', function(){
    setCurrent.bind(this)();
    deleteRun();
});
```